# Trouble styling input within span as one element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form in my Rails 3 app that uses `span` as placeholders, positioned inside of `input` fields within `divs`. For most form fields, the structure looks like:

```
<div class="holds">
  <span class="holder">Placeholder</span>
  <input>Input</input
</div>
```

However on one field I want the actual `input` to be wrapped in text so the `input` field flows like a sort of fill in the blank. So the HTML rendered would look something like this:

```
<div><span>It is supposed to <input id="foo" placeholder="ex: rain"> today</span></div>
```

However I'm having trouble styling that particular `div` so that it is uniform. I would like the div to:

- Have one consistent border around both `span` and `input` but no borders inside of the `span` on the left and right of the `input`. (See below in my jsFiddle that I clearly don't have that fixed.)
- Focus the entire `div` when the `input` is focused. (I attempted this in my jsFiddle below but my beginner status has limited me.)
- Ideally, I'd also position the cursor inside of the input if the `span` is clicked. However that's not high priority.

Here is a link to my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akCsP/1/). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the placeholder attribute on the input?

Comment: I actually use the placeholder on the input in my jsFiddle. On the rest I hadn't because of styling and browser support.

Comment: There are a few jQuery plugins that will "progressively enhance" the browsers that don't support it.  Try googling for them.

Comment: Will do, thanks. However, I'm not concerned with placeholder in this question. My priority here is to figure out how to style the input field in a way that puts the input between text, and that everything is wrapped in one border with one focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this demo does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/akCsP/2/

i replaced the div with a label, one of the benefits of using elements appropriately is default user agent behavior: focusing on a label auto magically focuses on its related form control, in this case the input.

wasn't sure about how you wanted the style div on focus, so i just used the input's focus styles

Comment: Wow, great! And +1 for the default label behavior.